python auto click html element
I have a URL of a page contains only a video element with media control, there is an options button to download the video, how to click this download button using python and selenium?
page body:
<body>
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
<source src="https:somelink" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>

NOTE: I tried to modify the html before loading the page, but the URL broke (video didn't even downloaded in video element)

I found another way to download the video using requests.
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
s = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
  s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
response = s.get(URL, stream=True)
print(response.status_code)
with open("output.mp4", 'wb') as f:
  f.write(response.content)

